# JavaScript error, push is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, push

I just started to learn JavaScript. I made a save function to save data to local storage, but everytime I try to save a data, it always get this error: push is not a function.

The error occurs in this piece of code:

```
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
issues.push(issue);
```

I'm trying to get data from local storage. var issues is supposed to be an array of objects, so then I can push another object into it.

This is the complete code:

```
function fetchIssues () {
  var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
  var issuesList = document.getElementById('issuesList');

  issuesList.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    var id = issues[i].id;
    var desc = issues[i].description;
    var severity = issues[i].severity;
    var assignedTo = issues[i].assignedTo;
    var status = issues[i].status;

    issuesList.innerHTML +=   '<div class="well">'+
    '<h6>Issue ID: ' + id + '</h6>'+
    '<p><span class="label label-info">' + status + '</span></p>'+
    '<h3>' + desc + '</h3>'+
    '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> ' + severity + ' '+
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ' + assignedTo + '</p>'+
    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="setStatusClosed(\''+id+'\')">Close</a> '+
    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteIssue(\''+id+'\')">Delete</a>'+
    '</div>';
  }
}

document.getElementById('issueInputForm').addEventListener('submit', saveIssue);

function saveIssue(e) {
  var issueId = chance.guid();
  var issueDesc = document.getElementById('issueDescInput').value;
  var issueSeverity = document.getElementById('issueSeverityInput').value;
  var issueAssignedTo = document.getElementById('issueAssignedToInput').value;
  var issueStatus = 'Open';
  var issue = {
    id: issueId,
    description: issueDesc,
    severity: issueSeverity,
    assignedTo: issueAssignedTo,
    status: issueStatus
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('issues') === null) {
    var issues = [];
    issues.push(issue);
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
  } else {
    var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    issues.push(issue);
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
  }

  document.getElementById('issueInputForm').reset();

  fetchIssues();

  e.preventDefault(); 
}

function setStatusClosed (id) {
  var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));

  for(var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    if (issues[i].id == id) {
      issues[i].status = "Closed";
    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));

  fetchIssues();
}

function deleteIssue (id) {
  var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));

  for(var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    if (issues[i].id == id) {
      issues.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));

  fetchIssues();
}
```

Comment: I would think that the json string you are parsing is not a representation of an array but an object. If it's an object, I don't think they provide a 'push' method.

Comment: Can you `console.log(issues)` before calling push? That way you can see what the value actually is

Comment: Could you try to reduce your issue to a [mcve], [edit] your question and include it there?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't considering the case where there is nothing set in that storage key yet.

Try changing:

```
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
```

To

```
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues') || '[]');
```

This will return an empty array if `getItem('issues')` is null or empty

I suggest you wrap this in a  helper function and replace the multiple instances where you call `JSON.parse(getItem)`

Comment: But there’s already `if (localStorage.getItem('issues') === null)`.

Comment: @Xufox multiple instances of `getItem` also